# Score add in game center

Tags: objective-c

i'm trying to save my score in game center but it wont 'upload' my score. i'm using the code;

Viewdidload;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



    [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
              NSLog(@"Succes (viewdidload) %i",counter);
        } else {
              NSLog(@"Fail (viewdidload) %i",counter);
        }
    }];

}
```

The NSlogs outputs;

```
2012-01-06 08:46:03.804 iTouchers[313:707] Succes (viewdidload) 26

2012-01-06 08:45:52.203 iTouchers[313:707] Succes 26
```

Anyone know the problem? Or you just can't add a score in sandbox mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the counter's type that you use, but you can try to replace the sentence:

```
scoreReporter.value = counter;
```

for this one:

```
scoreReporter.value = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:counter] longLongValue];
```

In my case, I use the type **int64_t** for the variable "counter", and it works fine.

Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html) requires use this type.

Comment: Counter is the score i want to add in the .h file; `int counter;`

Comment: In your subScore function you can do:

    `int64_t score1 = score;`

and then use "score1" in:

    `scoreReporter.value = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:score1] longLongValue];`